# keep flash music player across page refresh/change

Tags: javascript, ajax, page-lifecycle

I am trying to have a flash-based music player on my page which continues playing a song even when you refresh or go to another page within the web site.

I whant do this like facebook footer

i read  this topic 
 [How does Facebook keep the header and footer fixed while loading a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668431/how-does-facebook-keep-the-header-and-footer-fixed-while-loading-a-different-page)

but i have loadpage()  and location.hash problem

if someone know how its made plz tell me

Comment: What "loadpage() and location.hash problem" are you having? What exactly have you done, what did you expect to happend and what exactly happend instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var headerLinks = header.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, l = headerLinks.length; i < l; i++) 
{ 
 headerLinks[i].onclick = function() {    
var href = this.href;   
 //Load the AJAX page (this is a whole other topic)    
loadPage(href);      
//Update the address bar to make it look like you were redirected   
 location.hash = '#' + href;    
//Unfocus the link to make it look like you were redirected    
this.blur();   
 //Prevent the natural HTTP redirect    
return false;  

}}
```

CSS:

```
#Footer  {  
font-size:xx-small;   
text-align:left;   
width:100%;   
bottom:0px;   
position:fixed;   
left:0px;   
background-color: #CCCCCC;   
border-top: 1px solid #999999;   
padding:4px;   
padding-right:20px;   
color:#666666; 
}
```

I have done so 
this code not worked,  i want to do not refresh area for music player like google videos or facebook task bar

I have done so

```
function links() {
    //var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var headerLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0, l = headerLinks.length; i < l; i++) {
        headerLinks[i].onclick = function() {
            var href = this.href;
            loadPage(href);
            window.location.hash = "#" + href;
            this.blur();
           return false;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    links();
}
```

i whant to all links to modify but it's not worked

Comment: More details, please!  What does it mean that it hasn't worked?  What happened?  Did you get an error message?  Did your browser crash?  Did nothing happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are pretty new to javascript.  If that is the case then doing a full ajax site is probably not the place to start.  I think you should try going old-school and using frames to accomplish this.  (This is how Google Video used to function, and Google Images still uses this technique.)

```
<html>
    <frameset rows="200px,*,200px">
        <frame src="yourPageHeaderWithFlashPlayer.html" noresize="noresize"/>
        <frame src="yourMainContent.html" noresize="noresize"/>
        <frame src="yourPageFooter.html" noresize="noresize"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

That would work for a 200px header and 200px footer.  If you need more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp.

Comment: i know that but  i want to do it using javascript

Comment: Prestaul is correct -- what you're trying to do is very advanced and is going to require a deep understanding of the language. If you're not *very* comfortable in Javascript, proceed with caution.