# Unable to persist header like Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am currently a beginner JavaScript learner. I was trying some special code logics found on various top websites like Facebook. One of them I found here: [How does Facebook keep the header and footer fixed while loading a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668431/how-does-facebook-keep-the-header-and-footer-fixed-while-loading-a-different-pag). But I am unable to execute it properly. Following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">TEST HEADER
<a href="sample2.htm">SAMPLE</a></div>
<p>OUTSIDE</p>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var header = document.getElementById('header');
        var headerLinks = header.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for (var i = 0, l = headerLinks.length; i < l; i++) {
            headerLinks[i].onclick = function () {
                var href = this.href;

                //Load the AJAX page (this is a whole other topic)
                loadPage(href);

                //Update the address bar to make it look like you were redirected
                location.hash = '#' + href;

                //Unfocus the link to make it look like you were redirected
                this.blur();

                //Prevent the natural HTTP redirect
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Actually the motive of my code is not just to persist header on a page but also when navigating to other page. The header should not reload when navigated to other page.

**Solution from the answer by Bill F.:**

Forgot to define `loadPage()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadPage() {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="type/html" data="sample2.htm" ></object>';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Look into CSS positioning: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: Actually its not CSS header persist technique. I want the effect mentioned in the linked question. CSS will only hold header upward but when you click on a link on that page it will reload the header. While in Facebook the header remains while navigating to other page. Only content changes.

Comment: Look into AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: No actually this code is working code. But its not working for me because I think I am not calling the script at correct position. I want to know where should I call the script?

Comment: Look into single page apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the function `loadPage` is what you're doing wrong. Presumably, that function will use AJAX to retrieve a page's contents, whether in JSON, HTML, XML, CSV, whatever.

Comment: Apologies, actually I am not a JS expert and I didn't knew that it is a user-defined function. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the position of a div fixed even while scrolling using **position:fixed**

```
#header
{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Actually the motive of my code is not just to persist header on a page but also when navigating to other page. The header should not reload when navigated to other page.

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to do it properly all you need to do is  create 2 seperate container divs,1 for the nav bar(which you want to remain) and 2 for the content which you want changed then simply retrieve the data from an external page

CODE representation

```
<div class="container_for_persistent_nav-bar">
</div>

<div class="container_for_divs_that_are_not_persistent">
</div>
```

then just bind a click event to links that will,1.on click clear the div container for NON_PERSISTENT DIVS and then,2.load the divs from a separate page